# simple game development on linux

Tags: linux, pygame

I'd like to develop simple 2d games on linux. Something like one below. The only decent tecnology I've found was PyGame. Is there any other worth taking a look? Is there a possibility to develop flash games on linux?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I will have to agree with previous user , pygame is an amazing powerful and easy to use library.

Now about your flash games, there is a back door.

First forget about flash. Yes I know that this seems a bit out of topic , but no worries you can compensate for this.

Now python has something called Pyjamas, dont laugh its actually a very serious package. What pyjamas does is to convert python code to javascript code, all this happens automatically and you dont need to know a single line of javascript , even though knowing javascript could help as well. Of course the benefits of converting python to javascript means that not only you can run python apps inside any browser and any device supporting a browser including iPad, iphone, and pretty much anything else you can also use javascript libraries. Actually you can use only javascript libraries , so forget about using pygame with pyjamas.

Now HTML5 is the future, its still an ongoing project and far from finished, but YouTube already is using it with alot of success. Html5 together with the new version of javascrip offer features very similar to Flash, with the added advantage unlike Flash which is tied to Adobe , HTML5 is open source and a web standard. That means that borwser support Html5 out of the box with no need to install anything. So you could use HTML5 and Javascript to build your browser games. I think that HTML5 will replace the Flash in the near future. Remember because you will be using pyjama you will writing your code in python only, but of course you could mix it with some javascript code if you wish so.

I will advice for the time being epxlore pygame , because its dead easy to use, and when the right time comes and feel confident with python, take a look at pyjamas and fire away your browser games.  The important thing to remember is that unlike other easy to lear language Python is a serious language used for almost anything, so you never run out of option. So do your coding and have fun.

Oh in case you need to check out pyjamas its right here.

[Pyjamas Website](http://pyjs.org/)

Answer (score 1):

[Here's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_game_engines) a list of some open source game engines in general. You'll want to look at the cross-platform, 2D-oriented engines and see which one best meets your needs as far as programming language and features.

However, PyGame is pretty well-developed, and Python is an exceptionally easy and fun language to do anything in, including game development. I recommend you check out PyGame first, I think it would work well for your task.

As for developing flash games on Linux, there's little chance of that. To develop flash games you need Adobe's suite, and it is only compatible with Windows and Mac. So unless your computer can handle the stress of Adobe software (which is pretty high) in an emulated environment (Wine, which adds considerable hardware overhead), you'd need Windows or Mac OS X to do that. You can still play them, however.

Answer (score 1):

There are flash libraries for games that work in linux. It's a but more of a pain in the ass but maybe all the hassle will teach you a thing or two ?

Here are some usefull links
http://flashgamedojo.com/go/
http://www.flixel.org/download.html (mentions some linux options)